# Golang tcp-tls over socks5 proxy client

Tags: go, ssl, tcp, proxy

I create a dialer via

```golang
dialer := &net.Dialer{}
```

and a TLS dialer via

```golang
tlsDialer := &tls.Dialer{
    NetDialer: dialer,
    Config:    &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true},
}
```

Then I create a socks5 proxy dialer by using

```golang
proxyDialer, err := proxy.SOCKS5("tcp", "127.0.0.1:1080", nil, proxy.Direct)
```

How can I connect remote server though the socks5 proxy?
In other way, how to nest three dialer in the order of `net.Dialer->tls.Dialer->proxy.Dialer` and finally using `proxyDialer.Dial("tcp", "remote:port")` to connect the server?

My Env:

- OS: Windows 10 x64
- Golang: 1.16 (no CGO)

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)
First time asking question in SOF, if I missed sth to say pls tell me :)

Comment: A Dialer is used to establish a connection - but there is only a single connection to establish. Create the connection using proxyDialer, then use [tls.Client](https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/tls#Client) on the connection given by proxyDialer to "upgrade" it to a tls.Conn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for [@Steffen Ullrich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3081018/steffen-ullrich)

A Dialer is used to establish a connection - but there is only a single connection to establish. Create the connection using proxyDialer, then use tls.Client on the connection given by proxyDialer to "upgrade" it to a tls.Conn.

Just "upgrade" proxy connection to tls

```golang
proxyDialer, err := proxy.SOCKS5("tcp", "proxyserver:1080", nil, proxy.Direct)
conn, err = proxyDialer.Dial("tcp", "server:port")
conn = tls.Client(conn, &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true})
```