# Golang TLS socket ignores HTTP_PROXY environment variable

Tags: go, tcp

I'm making a HTTP request using socket in Golang. I need the request to be made via proxy server to hide my ip. I set the proxy using `os.Setenv("HTTP_PROXY", "http://ip:port")` however the socket ignores this variable and makes the request without the proxy. Here's my code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/tls"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func sendSocketRequest() {
    recv := make([]byte, 4096)
    conn, _ := tls.Dial("tcp", "api.ipify.org"+":443", nil)
    conn.Write([]byte("GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: api.ipify.org\r\n\r\n"))
    conn.Read(recv)
    fmt.Println(string(recv))
    conn.Close()
}

func main() {
    os.Setenv("HTTP_PROXY", "http://193.27.23.62:9150")
    os.Setenv("HTTPS_PROXY", "http://193.27.23.62:9150")

    sendSocketRequest()
}
```

In addition, I tried that with normal HTTP client `net/http` and it worked just fine. The request was made via proxy.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Connect via Proxy while using UTLS and HTTP 1.1 Request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60624954/connect-via-proxy-while-using-utls-and-http-1-1-request), [Golang tcp-tls over socks5 proxy client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71182538/golang-tcp-tls-over-socks5-proxy-client). In short: you need to first create a Conn using the proxy and then use this Conn inside tls.Client.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you for your help, I'm glad to see your input to my problem. Here's my code. I receive blank response from the server. https://go.dev/play/p/FL0ymZdWM6x

Comment: There is no tls.Client in your code to upgrade the plain TCP to TLS

Comment: Added it, still the same result. https://go.dev/play/p/cBAdrhvgsl2 Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich To recap, this is what I have so far https://go.dev/play/p/57q1Wn12g1S
This approach returns blank response (example here https://go.dev/play/p/57q1Wn12g1S)

Comment: You forgot to also call `Handshake()`  on the TLS connection.

Comment: I figured it out, turns out I had to specify ServerName. I'll add an answer soon, thank you for your help!